# Dictionary key doesn't exist wheras it does exist

Tags: c#, dictionary

I use a `Dictionary<string, Test>` to store some datas, where the key is a file path. To display this dictionary I create a treeview with node names being the key of the corresponding test.

When I try to get back one value, I use:

```
Test test = Tests[node.Name];
```

But I throw me that:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

So I made a few manual debug:

```
Console.WriteLine(node.Name + Environment.NewLine + Tests.First().Key);
```

Which outputs:

```
P:\poolman\LY21\2015\LY21_2015-03-25_03.xml <- The node name
P:\poolman\LY21\2015\LY21_2015-03-25_03.xml <- The dictionary first key
```

But keep crashing. How can I get rid of this?

---

I've added

```
Console.WriteLine(node.Name.Length + " " + Tests.First().Key.Length);
```

Which output

```
43 43
```

So it's not about the length.

In the Immediate window I tried this:

```
node.Name == Tests.First().Key
true
```

I **really** don't understand.

### And one more lovely edit:

```
Tests.ContainsKey(node.Name)
true
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80296/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-dictionary-key-doesnt-exist-wheras-it-does-exi).